# Using jQuery to change the css style of angularJS tree root node

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

Here is my jsfidder: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0n1ydream/u8m47bhw/).

I'm trying to use the [AngularJS Treeview](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview) and it's the [official demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/b9Pnw/) .

```
<div
  data-angular-treeview="true"
  data-tree-model="data"
  data-node-id="value"
  data-node-label="names"
  data-node-children="nodes" >
</div>
```

I want to change the css style of the root node, without impacting the children nodes. In this demo, it means to change the three root nodes' style (for example, just change their background color to red). How to do this with jQuery? Or you have a better way? Please tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole structure is made of nested unordered lists (`<li>` elements within `<ul>` lists) and each list element has an icon element `<i>` and the text in a `<span>`.

So if you want to select only the parent element you can use a direct descendant selector `>` which will return only the first direct child. See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mastazi/r301gpwj/

```
/* style only parent */
$(document).ready( function(){
    // give border only to first-level element
    $('div#tree > ul > li').css('border', '3px solid red');
    // green text for first level
    $('div#tree > ul > li').css('color', 'green');
    //reset to black for inner levels after first
    $('div#tree > ul > li ul li').css('color', 'black');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I find the way that using element selector can not meet my need. In fact, while using the treeviewer, I try to add a button with dropmenu after the node which provides some operation such as update and so on. Using element selector with `$('div#tree > ul > li').append()` can add a button, but it cannot get the node value shown in <li>.

Comment: I try to add the button while generate the tree by modifing angulartreeview.js, but every node(whether it is a root node or child node) has a button after it.

Comment: As shown in this http://jsfiddle.net/0n1ydream/yrcat3dq, how to remove the `<span class="background">test</span>` from the children nodes?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Finally, I solve this problem. To the root node that needed special operation, I use ng-repeat. To those children nodes, I use the plugin to generate the tree view. If you can slove this with the remove() api or other methods, please tell me.

Comment: Hey @0n1ydream, yes it seems you solved the problem by modifying the angular side, I was sticking to jQuery because you mentioned "how to do this with jQuery?" in your question.

Comment: You are asking how to remove the span element, it would be something like `$('div#tree ul > li > span').css('display', 'none');` however you are NOT forced to use jQuery and in fact acting on the code that generates the tree in the first place might be a better way.